# XGBoost feature importance has all features but decision tree doesn't

Tags: python, feature-selection, xgboost

I have used XGBoost to train a model with 400 features. My understanding is that since the max_depth is default at only 6, and 2^6 < 400, not all features will end up in the tree.

How come when I output the feature importance chart, it shows every single feature with above 0 importance? The decision tree output clearly shows that not every feature has been used in the final tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XGBoost iteratively trains many trees (=boosting). So there is not only one tree.
For example you can plot a single tree, see: https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-gradient-boosting-decision-trees-xgboost-python/

A basic decision tree algorithm creates just one tree. If you apply pruning to the tree not all features would be present in the tree. The first split would be the one with the highest importance, ...

Comment: So when I am using XGBoost.predict, its using all the trees it made? How does it combine the outputs?

Comment: Yes, take a look at: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9862/classification-using-xgboost-predictions

Comment: But isn't that only if I set num_parallel_trees = to something? Ie. a randomforest?

Comment: Boosting is an Ensembling Training Method which creates multiple trees. See official paper, section 2.1 - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754.pdf

Comment: The first split won't necessarily be the on the feature of highest importance, depending on your definition of importance.